# Trouble with asynchronous functions in node.js

Tags: node.js

I'm very new to node, and I'm trying to pull a list of IDs from an API, iterate through that list for each ID saving the output, and ultimately rename each file generated. The code below is the closest I've come, and while it works sometimes, it frequently fails as I believe one function isn't waiting for the other to complete (e.g. tries to read before a write), but I'm sure I have other issues going on.

```
const apiKey = inputData.apiKey

var https = require('https');
var sync = require('sync');
var fs = require('fs');

var JSONfileloc = "./pdfs/file.json"
var queryurl = 'https://intakeq.com/api/v1/intakes/summary?startDate=2018-01-01'
var authHeaders = { 'X-Auth-Key': apiKey }
var queryOpts = { method: 'GET', headers: authHeaders}


function handleFile (error, file) 
{
   if (error) return console.error('Ran into a problem here', error)
 }


fetch(queryurl, queryOpts)
.then
(function findAPI(res, err)
    {
    if( err ) 
        {       console.log('I cant find the API '+err)         }
        return res.json()
        {console.log('found the API!')}
    }
)

.then (function itID(res, err)
    { 
    if( err ) 
        {       console.log('I cant iterate the API '+err)      }
    for(var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) 
        {
           var intakeID=res[i].Id;
           var APIoptions={   host:"intakeq.com",   path:"/api/v1/intakes/"+ intakeID,   headers: authHeaders };
           var PDFoptions={   host:"intakeq.com",   path:"/api/v1/intakes/"+ intakeID+'/pdf',   headers: authHeaders };
    console.log('Working on ID:'+intakeID)
    var JSONrequest = https.get(APIoptions, writeJSON)

    }})


//READ JSON FUNCTION

function readJSON (err, data) 

{
        if (err) throw err;
        if(data.indexOf('New Patient Forms') >= 0)

        var contents = fs.readFileSync(JSONfileloc, handleFile);
        var jsonContent = JSON.parse(contents)

        //pull PT Name
        pName = (jsonContent.ClientName);
        console.log('The Patient Name Is ' + jsonContent.ClientName)

        //pull PT DOB
        pDob = (jsonContent.Questions[3].Answer)
        console.log('Patient DOB Is ' + jsonContent.Questions[3].Answer)

        //pull Form Type
        pForm = (jsonContent.QuestionnaireName)
        console.log('The Form Submitted is ' + jsonContent.QuestionnaireName)

        //rename and move JSON
        fs.rename("./pdfs/file.json", './JSONLogs/'+pName+' '+pForm+' '+Date.now()+'.json', function(err) {
        if ( err ) console.log('Problem renaming! ' + err)
        else console.log('Copying & Renaming JSON File!');
        })

        };

//WRITE JSON FUNCTION
function writeJSON(response, err)
    {
    var JSONfile = fs.createWriteStream(JSONfileloc, handleFile);
    if (err) throw err;
    response.pipe(JSONfile);
    console.log('JSON Created')
    fs.readFile(JSONfileloc, readJSON)
    }
```

The research I've done leads me to believe that async.forEach is probably the right approach here, but I've been having a hard time getting that to work properly. Thanks in advance and any suggestions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const apiKey = inputData.apiKey

var https = require('https');
var sync = require('sync');
var fs = require('fs');

var JSONfileloc = "./pdfs/file.json"
var queryurl = 'https://intakeq.com/api/v1/intakes/summary?startDate=2018-01-01'
var authHeaders = {
    'X-Auth-Key': apiKey
}
var queryOpts = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: authHeaders
}


function handleFile(error, file) {
    if (error) return console.error('Ran into a problem here', error)
}


fetch(queryurl, queryOpts)
    .then(function findAPI(res) {
        return res.json();
    })
    .then(function itID(res) {
        const JSONRequests = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
            var intakeID = res[i].Id;
            var APIoptions = {
                host: "intakeq.com",
                path: "/api/v1/intakes/" + intakeID,
                headers: authHeaders
            };
            var PDFoptions = {
                host: "intakeq.com",
                path: "/api/v1/intakes/" + intakeID + '/pdf',
                headers: authHeaders
            };
            // https.get has response as a stream and not a promise
            // This `httpsGet` function converts it to a promise
            JSONRequests.push(httpsGet(APIoptions, i));
        }
        return Promise.all(JSONRequests);
    })

function httpsGet(options, filename) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        https.get(options, (response) => {
            // The WriteJSON function, just for brewity
            // Otherwise pass resolve to the seperate writeJSON and call it in there
            var JSONfile = fs.createWriteStream(filename + ".json");
            response.pipe(JSONfile);
            JSONfile.on('close', () => {
                readJSON(filename + ".json").then(() => {
                    resolve();
                })
            })
        })
    })
}


//READ JSON FUNCTION
function readJSON(filename) {
    // if (err) throw err;

    var contents = fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf-8'); // removed handleFile as readFileSync does not allow callbacks, added format
    var jsonContent = JSON.parse(contents)

    //  Make your conditional checks here with the jsonContents


    //pull PT Name
    pName = (jsonContent.ClientName);
    console.log('The Patient Name Is ' + jsonContent.ClientName)

    //pull PT DOB
    pDob = (jsonContent.Questions[3].Answer)
    console.log('Patient DOB Is ' + jsonContent.Questions[3].Answer)

    //pull Form Type
    pForm = (jsonContent.QuestionnaireName)
    console.log('The Form Submitted is ' + jsonContent.QuestionnaireName)

    //rename and move JSON
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.rename("./pdfs/file.json", './JSONLogs/' + pName + ' ' + pForm + ' ' + Date.now() + '.json', function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('Problem renaming! ' + err);
                reject(err);
            } else {
                console.log('Copying & Renaming JSON File!');
                resolve();
            }
        })
    })

};
```

Updated to convert `https.get` response stream to return a Promise which can be handled much better.

Comment: Thanks so much! I'm getting the following error when running the revised code: 

"Unexpected end of JSON input at JSON.parse". Not immediately clear to me why that, is but I'll keep looking.

Comment: Any line number?

Comment: This is the full error message:
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at readJSON (C:\Users\UserName\intakeQapi\index.js:60:28)
    at IncomingMessage.response.on 
   (C:\Users\UserName\intakeQapi\index.js:49:9)
    at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1055:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
    npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.

Comment: Can you see what the file at `JSONfileloc` looks like?

Comment: Looks like it creates the file, but it's blank, so nothing to parse.

Comment: Yeah, I missed that the `response` is a stream and I was using it like a Promise.

Comment: Looks like it's generating the same error and situation. file.json is generated, but has no contents, so it throws an 'unexpected end of JSON input error".

Comment: Well I really appreciate the effort either way and it all helps me to learn what I'm doing here. Everything looks like it's working just as you wanted until this point. If I comment this out, the files write fine. response.on('end', () => { readJSON().then(() => { resolve(); })   I believe the code isn't waiting for the write to complete befor reading.  I added artifical delays with setTimeout, and was able to see this happening (It'll read a single file if I set a delay of 500). It seems like I need each function to wait until the other is done doing its thing.

Comment: I did some researching around and found that when you pipe a stream, the piped stream is handled independently of the actual stream. So, you have to listen to the 'close' event of the `fs.createWriteStream` instead

Comment: I had read similar and had given that a shot as well. Using the new code, this never executes (it DOES run with 'close', but throws an unexpected end of JSON input) :    

  response.on('end', () => {
              console.log('Check if read triggers')
              readJSON().then(() => {
                    resolve();

Comment: It's getting further! It just looks like one function isn't waiting for the other to finish. It will work right for a couple iterations and then throw the error:
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename

Comment: Now it's the error with remaining. You probably want to name files differently instead of just one static string. Maybe like Date.now().toString()

Comment: That's an approach I tried, but unless I'm not understanding properly, I'd run into issues with Date.now() because the time difference between when it's written and read. I did try to assign each file name by intakeid, but I'm still seeming to run into an issue where it's attempting to read a file before it's finished writing, so it throws an invalid character error. I'll keep working on it and appreciate all your help.

Comment: Your latest update works perfectly! I changed fs.rename to reference filename as well, and everything is exactly how I need it. Very much appreciated!